# Razor RenderPage my.js without HttpException

Tags: razor

Suppose I want to render javascript from an external file inline into my layout file for performance reasons.

If I use the following Razor code

```
<script>
    @RenderPage("~/Content/my.js")
</script>
```

results in

> ### Server Error in '/' Application.
>
> The following file could not be
>   rendered because its extension ".js" might not be supported:
>   "~/Content/my.js".

If I merely rename my javascript file to `my.js.cshtml`

```
<script>
    @RenderPage("~/Content/my.js.cshtml")
</script>
```

The peasants rejoice.

### The question:

Is there any *simple* way for me to prevent RenderPage from nagging such that I can tell it that the `.js` extension is fine?

---

With some feedback from [@choudeshell](https://twitter.com/choudeshell) one potential solution is:

```
<compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5">
  <buildProviders>
    <remove extension=".js"/>
    <add extension=".js" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.RazorBuildProvider,
                               System.Web.WebPages.Razor"/>
  </buildProviders>  

</compilation>
```

What type of side effects would there be from removing whatever the default is for .js, any?

Comment: And yes I know what I'm doing, I know about bundling/minification/caching. For illustration purposes you could view my.js to be an asynchronous scriptloader.

Comment: This can help:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5925679/inline-javascript-in-my-razor-file-can-i-have-this-included-from-an-external

Comment: @bob I had thought of reading it off disk myself but I'd much rather leverage the built in RenderPage that I'm sure operates in a less naive fashion than anything I would write for IO. That question does specifically mention doing .cshtml since my question is about avoiding renaming the file I would say this question does not duplicate that link.