# How to SEO my React GitHub Pages personal site?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, seo, github-pages

I have a GitHub Pages personal webpage built with Create-React-App (`[username].github.io`). I have an `h1` tag with my full name in the `noscript` tag, and I also have it render for my homepage with an `h1` tag. My name is fairly unique, and when you search it up, it's just stuff related to me, but I'd like my webpage to show up as well. I have some `meta` tags like `description` in the `header` with my full name as well, and I can't seem to make my webpage show up in a Google search. What is the best way to do this?

Comment: possible duplicate of existing Q&A material, e.g. [42358158](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42358158/367456) and related.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways how you can improve your SEO for the website.

1. If you want to be higher in Google, you can use `<meta name="google-site-verification" content="...">` and the [other useful metatags](https://developers.google.com/search/blog/2006/05/more-about-meta-tag-verification).
2. Show the website to your friends and colleagues, and try to bring more attraction to it. If your website is not immediately in the Google search - it's okay. Imagine every new website will be accessible for the whole internet on Google search within seconds; I guess it would require more server power for Google
3. You can try some SSR (server-side rendering) frameworks for your application, like [Next.js](https://nextjs.org/) or [Remix](https://remix.run/). These guys can improve your website's SEO optimisation by having your website be built on the server while you still use your favourite `React`.

Additional reading:

I recommend you check the [Google SEO guide](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/fundamentals/get-on-google) for web developers, as it can explain some things better and wider.